# php mysql - update multiple rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql, rows

Ok, i have a checklist system that i am working on.  There is a page that pulls data from the database and displays it as a checklist.  I am trying to create a button that when pushed will reset the database to a certain state that i want.  Basically, i have a button that sends an ajax callout to a php page that executes an `UPDATE` query.  This query is as follows:

```
UPDATE $table SET value='$value', comments='$comments', editedBy='$editedBy', editedDate='$editedDate' WHERE projectId='$projectId';
```

I set the variables first of course, that's not my question.  Just pretend they have data.  My question is how can i repeat this query so that every row table *x* that has a projectId of *n* is updated?  I'm guessing this involves a for loop?

SIDE NOTE:  Since this query is just setting the value to `false` and making the `comments`, `editedBy`, and `editedDate` fields blank for every row in table *x* that has a projectId of *n*, is there a better way of doing this other than the `UPDATE` query?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm assuming that the problem here is that you do not know all the rows table X has which makes it troublesome to update or am I wrong?

Comment: This query updates all rows with the projectId you supply.

Comment: thanks @edem, as you and @Jesse said, i'll just give that query a try on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't sepcify a `LIMIT` in your `UPDATE` query, it will update every row it finds that satisfies your where clause.

Now, if you're updating the projects table and `projectID` is your primary key, you'll need to run a loop to update other `projectID`s. If you're not updating the project table, then your update query will update any record that has a foreign key match to the project ID you specified.

Does that help?

Comment: thanks!  I was thinking that might be the case but i didn't want to just run the query and screw up the database..wouldn't be the end of the world, just more work.  Thanks for the help.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: yea, it worked!  Guess i knew what i was doing after all.  Thanks for confirming it for me.  Now, is there a better way of removing data from a column on a specific row other than updating the row with a blank value?  Or does this suffice?

Comment: Depending on your constraints, you could set the value = NULL in your SQL query. However, a blank value should suffice in most applications.